# How to avoid complex value for square root of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to find square root of a matrix $Z$ which is a symmetric matrix using eigen values. So I find the eigenvalues($A$) and eigenvectors($B$) of $Z$ and find $B A^{1/2} B$. But because of small negative eigenvalues  (I think due to rounding errors), I get complex values for A^{1/2}. So square root of matrix $Z$ is complex. How to proceed in that case so that I get real square root (As far as I know square root of a symmetric matrix should be symmetric)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem. If you are certain that your matrix is *supposed* to be positive semidefinite, but is not so due only to small numerical errors, then you should simply replace any negative eigenvalues that you find in $A$ with zeros before computing $BA^{1/2}B$.

But again, you must be sure that your original matrix was supposed to be positive semidefinite before proceeding in this fashion. Use this as an opportunity to confirm that the preceding calculations are providing the expected results, so that your premise of positive semidefiniteness is valid.

Comment: Thank you fro your reply.My matrix is a sum of many covariance matrices. So I hope it is positive semi-definite.
When I computed square root of Z in Matlab (sqrtm(Z)), that also returns me a complex answer. Does that mean numerical error issue is there in Matlab also or my matrix is not positive semidefinite?

Comment: Yes, the numerical errors are in Matlab as well. Matlab isn't going to do this kind of rounding for you, you'll have to do it yourself.